# Using Adobe DTM to track CSS-based show/hide events

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm having some trouble figuring out the best way to get ADTM to fire when I show or hide a piece of content on one of my pages. Note, I'm simply toggling the style.display, not retrieving and inserting via AJAX.

I gather that it would be some sort of Event Base Rule with a custom condition to test the style.display value, but I'm unsure of which event I should actually be using. The closest one would seem to be "element exists", but that seems to only be for testing the presence of DOM nodes.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: how is the content shown/hidden? e.g. what event makes it hide/show? I'm asking because there is no "onshow" or "onhide" type event, not even natively in javascript or w/ jQuery. closest way to do that is to write code that checks for it every x amount of time, which isn't very efficient. So it would be better to try and attach it to whatever is actually making it show/hide

Comment: A set of Prev/Next buttons have onclick event handlers which run script to toggle the style.display.

I was hoping that DTM might have a way of detecting the change in style.display of an object and triggering a rule, but alas. How does one then manually fire a tracking event using DTM?

Comment: soo.. why not just add a click event to the prev/next buttons? Or am I not understanding the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this would be to use the "Enters Viewport" option.  When the item visibility is set to display and the user can see the content then this event is triggered.

-Rudi

****** Great DTM Content  *********** 
DTM Blog Posts:  http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/tag/dynamic-tag-management/
Full DTM Demo..no slides…just live demo:  https://outv.omniture.com/play/?v=B5ODcybDozpBfRAARKiVrQ7V9lMtrD1C

Comment: This works in most cases, but there are times when "enters viewport" doesn't pick up the show/hide events the way you'd expect. Sometimes it fires right away because the element is technically visible but hidden by other means such as transparency or moving off screen.

In cases like that, you need to write custom script that checks the state of whatever is hiding/showing it.